# How can I setup IKE VPN connection client on ubuntu with strongswan?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I want to setup a VPN Connection client on Ubuntu 16.0 with the attached Configuration, but I don't know the parameters to use in the ipsec.conf file of strongswan.

[image: The Required configuration in English]